# iOS chat-app: How do I notify the user that the app will not function anymore if the user leaves the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, chat

I'm developing a chat-app for iOS that must use an existing server API. The way it works is pretty straightforward: the app checks every given interval whether there are new messages on the server and displays them, plus, it sends the server new messages that the user typed.

When the user starts 'multi-tasking' or presses the home button, my app will go to the background and therefore will not be able to check the server for new messages. The server will automatically assume that the user stopped the chat when a certain timeout has been reached.

Often, the user isn't aware of the fact that when the app is put to the background, it is unable to maintain the connection to the server and will stop the chat. I'm looking for a method that will notify the user of this behavior as soon as the app is put to the background.

My current idea is to notify the user when `applicationWillResignActive` and/or `applicationDidEnterBackground` is fired, but I wouldn't know in what way. Can it be done in a way that complies with Apple's guidelines?

I'm aware of the fact that the best solution would be a different overall design of the software (e.g., using push notifications and no server-side chat termination by timeouts), but in this case I can't change that.

Comment: cant you show user an `UIAlert` via `applicationDidEnterBackground` when he press iphone home button?

Comment: no. Once home key pressed nothing can be done like alert

Comment: but a UILocalNotification :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would continue running in the background and set an `expiration handler block` (called by the os when you app is REALLY killed) and there `schedule a UILocalNotification`

use

`- (UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier)beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:(void (^)(void))handler`

Comment: You could use the background task to get almost ten minutes of time running in the background. You could use that to keep the connection alive, and then in the expiration handler you could use a local notification to let the user know they have been logged out due to inactivity.

Comment: @AmyWorrall :: yes.. 100% what I wrote ^^

Comment: We do it the same way btw and get much much more time quiet often

Comment: I was just trying to clarify what you get by using this approach — that's why I posted a comment rather than a new answer :)